# How to register custom String UserType when using JPA + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I want to always use my own custom type that extends the Hibernate `StringType` (also performs trimming and uppercasing). However I am having some issues on how to register it so it is always used instead of the default `StringType`, since I don't want to have to put the `@Type` annotation on every String.

When just using Hibernate I know I can register it in the Configuration using `registerTypeOverride`, or in the `hbm.cfg.xml`, But how do I achieve this when using Hibernate in combination with JPA2? (note: I know there's @Convertor with auto = true in jpa 2.1, but the AS I have to use doesn't support JPA2.1 yet)

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate provides the [`Integrator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/) interface that can be used for this. For example:

```
public class CustomUserTypesIntegrator implements Integrator {
    public void integrate(Configuration configuration,
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        // Register the custom user type mapping(s) with Hibernate.
        CustomUserType customUserType = new CustomUserType();
        configuration.registerTypeOverride(customUserType,
                new String[] { customUserType.returnedClass().getName() });
    }

    public void integrate(MetadataImplementor metadata,
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        // Nothing to do here.
    }

    public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        // Nothing to do here.
    }
}
```

This then needs to be registered by exposing it as a [Service Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) via Java's standard SPI mechanism. For example:

```
my-project/
  src/main/resources/
    META-INF/
      services/
        org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator
```

Which would contain something like:

```
com.example.CustomUserTypesIntegrator
```

For a reference on this, I recommend looking at how the [Jadira Usertype library](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/) does it: https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira/. In particular, I found their [`AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator`](https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira/blob/master/usertype.spi/src/main/java/org/jadira/usertype/spi/shared/AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java) class to be worth a look.

Comment: The "Integrator" solution did not work for me (Hibernate 4.2).  In "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl", the "typeRegistry" is created (as a copy from the Configuration) prior to the "Integrators" being called.  So the calling "configuration.registerTypeOverride(...)" in the "Integrator" is too late.